# Como utilizar psr-4 no composer com diferentes subpastas

Tags: composer, php

Estou criando um framework de teste. Utilizo composer para criar a estrutura do meu projeto.
O arquivo composer.json está assim:

```
{
   "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
         "App\\": "src/app/mvc/"
      }
   }
}
```

Dividi meu projeto com a seguinte estrutura:

C:\xampp\htdocs\webApp\src\app\mvc\

Em mvc tenho as seguintes subpastas: controller; model; view

Sendo que estou com problemas no namespace.

Por exemplo para o /model/model.php o código ficou:

```
<?php
   namespace App;
   class Model
   {
      public function getText($str = 'Olá mundo!')
      {
         return $str;
      }
   }
```

Para o controller/controller.php o código ficou:

```
<?php
   namespace App\controller;
   class Controller
   {
      public function index()
      {
        $model = new model\Model;
        $view = new view\View;
        $view->render($model->getText());
      }
   }
```

O php está retornando um erro no controller.php
Fatal error: Class 'App\controller\model\Model' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\webApp\src\app\mvc\controller\Controller.php on line 7

Alguém saberia informar o que está errado na configuração do psr4.

Comment: Tente isto `new \App\model\Model;`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento com essa modificação no arquivo controller.php ao tentar instanciar o model dá o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Class 'App\controller\app\model\Model' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\webApp\src\app\mvc\controller\Controller.php on line 7

Comment: O Model está na mesma pasta que o Controller? Não tem muito sentido este erro, vc colocou a barra na frente que eu sugeri? **Assim** `new \App\model\Model;` e **não** assim `new App\model\Model;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem algumas modificações para realizar no seu código.

A configuração do composer está correta. Entretanto, seus códigos PHP devem ser alterados.

Veja a sua configuração do composer:

> "App\": "src/app/mvc/"

Veja a sua estrutura:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\webApp\src\app\mvc\

Logo após, você criou a classe `Model` o arquivo `model.php`, resultando no seguinte caminho:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\webApp\src\app\mvc\model\model.php

Logo, o namespace correto dele deverá ser:

```
namespace App\model;

class Model {}
```

E você o criou como:

```
namespace App;
class Model { }
```

A chamada ao namespace também deve ser acertada. Por exemplo, dentro do namespace controller, pode ser realizado de duas formas:

```
namespace App\controller;

class Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
     $model = new \App\model\Model;
   }
}
```

Ou

```
namespace App\controller;

use \App\model; //é interpretado como "use \App\model as model"

class Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
     $model = new model\Model;
   }
}
```

ou ainda, em específico da classe:

```
namespace App\controller;

use \App\model\Model; //é interpretado como "use \App\model\model as Model"

class Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
     $model = new Model;
   }
}
```

Faltou um nível de `namespace`, que seria as pastas `model`, `controller` e `view`.

Outro detalhe importante, no windows o sistema de arquivos é case-insensitive, já no linux é case-sensitive. Logo, seu sistema de arquivos devem ter o mesmo case que os `namespaces` e `classes`.

Logo:

```
namespace App\model;

class Model {}
```

Deve ser:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\webApp\src\App\mvc\model\Model.php

Com a pasta `App` e o arquivo `Model.php`.

Mas isso é válido apenas para sistemas Linux, no seu caso é Windows mesmo (vai te dar dor de cabeça em deploy depois).

Comment: que tipo de dor de cabeça você se refere no momento do deploy?

Comment: Por exemplo, você está desenvolvendo em Windows e criou classe `Model` no arquivo `model.php` e, no seu ambiente, tudo funcionará perfeitamente. Ao realizar o deploy para um ambiente Linux e executar o código, a classe `Model` não será encontrada, pois, o composer procurará pelo arquivo `Model.php`. No Windows isso não importa, no Linux sim. Esse é um dos motivos do desenvolvimento em PHP ser encorajado no Linux.