# Problema namespace so funciona local

Tags: php, namespace

Estou tendo o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Kse\init\Bootstrap' not found in /home/dksec173/public_html/App/Route.php on line 8
```

No desenvolvimento os namespace estão funcionando corretamente, porem ao subir para o servidor aparece este erro ai, já tentei alterar os caminhos para ver se funcionada porem nada feito, meu namespace esta assim..

```
{
"require":{
    "php":">=5.6"
},

"autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "Kse\\":"vendor/Kse/",
        "App\\":"App/"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Seu servidor de dev é windows e o servidor de produção é linux?

Comment: De uma olhada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/194771/5007

Comment: o de dev é windows e de produção é.. Hostgator o servidor de produção..

Comment: Se o seu servidor de produção é Linux, você está com o problema do case do path. Veja no final do link que eu te mandei. O windows é case-insentive. O linux, por outro lado, não. Ou seja, o caminho deve ter o case (caracteres maísculos/minúsculos) exatamente igual ao que foi definido nas classes e no namespace.

Comment: Então eu utilizo windows para produção.. e os caracteres estão exatamente iguais, já verifiquei.. e no localhost ele roda certinho só quando vou subir no servidor que da esse problema...

Comment: a pasta `/home/` é comum do linux (apesar de não ser dominante). Poste os demais códigos, as partes relevantes aonde o código está sendo executado (e ocorre o erro) e a parte relevante da classe que quer chamar.

Comment: FAQ do hostgator: Todas as contas de hospedagem (P, M e G), revenda e VPS 1000-8000 vêm com:

Sistema operacional: Linux x86 CentOS 6.x (64 bit) – versão gratuita do RedHat.

Comment: Ae brother, deu uma olhada la pagina que você passou, entendi como melhor como funciona.. e realmente havia uma pasta que se chama `Init` e no namespace estava `init`, porem estou com outro erro aqui.. a maioria dos array que tenho declarado na applicação eu user entre `[ ]`.. e nenhum esta sendo aceito, por oque devo substituir para funcionar?

Comment: `[] == array()`. Mas não deveria dar esse problema. A sintaxe de colchetes (array short syntax) entrou na versão 5.4.

Comment: é não entendi tbm, subistitui aqui por `array()`, mas agora ele entra na `index` e fica tudo branco não aparece nem erro.. to lascado kkkk